# New tables when deal with "query based modeling" in cassandra

Tags: mongodb, cassandra

Often after initial modeling and database is live and running, we may need to create another table which is optimized for new requirements.

We need to take 2 points into consideration:

**(1) Populate this new table with existing data**

**(2) Minimize the downtime required for such activity if absolute needed. For example, how to sync the data when data is continuously come in?**

I did some initial research on this, this is one approach given by "SmartCat labs". Could you share your ideas how to address this per your view?

Believe it's common challenge for these database with "query based modeling", like MongoDB and Cassandra.

SmartCat labs URL: https://github.com/smartcat-labs/cassandra-migration-tool-java